# Cannot connect to HTTPS port on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, https

I've installed a new SSL certificate and set up Nginx to use it. But requests time out when trying to hit HTTPS on the site. When I telnet to my domain on port 80 it connects, but times out on port 443. I'm not sure if there's some defaults on Ubuntu preventing a connection. cURL also times out to the HTTPS address but responds to regular HTTP.

UFW status shows:

```
443  ALLOW    Anywhere
```

netstat -a shows:

```
tcp        0      0 *:https                 *:*                     LISTEN
```

nmap localhost shows:

```
443/tcp  open  https
```

The relevant block in the Nginx config is:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    listen 80;
    root /path/to/app;
    server_name mydomain.com

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://mydomain.com;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Edit: having tried a whole range of nginx configuration options, I'm really doubting it's the setup. If the ssl-bundle.crt is screwed up, would it cause the time out to happen? If so I can revert to PositiveSSL for support.

Comment: Telnet times out because the server waits for you to start with a SSL Client Hello packet, which you don't send.  Did you even try with a browser?

Comment: Yes. On a browser I can access the site via HTTP but times out via HTTPS. I'm not too familiar with telneting or SSL. How would you attempt the protocol with an example packet?

Comment: Use `curl` instead which handles everything for you.

Comment: @NathanC well same result.

Comment: @Simpleton: have you checked the log files of nginx for error messages?

Comment: @Simpleton: I'm sure it is wrong to have listen 443 and listen 80 within the same config block, because for port 80 you want http (no ssl) while for 443 https (ssl).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yep, nginx configtest shows ok.

Comment: It shows ok, but it is probably not what you want. Of course you can use port 80 with https or port 443 with http, but then you will have to specify protocol and port explicitly in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    listen 80;
    root /path/to/app;
    server_name mydomain.com

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://mydomain.com;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

(remove `ssl on;`, add `ssl` to `listen 443;`)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to agree to Steffen's comment (listen 443 and listen 80 in same server block).

Please handle HTTP and HTTPS in different server blocks. I assume that the second listen directive has overwritten your first listen directive. Additionally I have missed the "ssl" keyword in your listen-directives for port 443.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    root /path/to/app;
    server_name mydomain.com

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://mydomain.com;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    root /path/to/app;
    server_name mydomain.com

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://mydomain.com;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

As user xofer reported, it's possible to have HTTP and HTTPS in one server block. So an example for this all-in-one solution as well:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    root /path/to/app;
    server_name mydomain.com

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://mydomain.com;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: from [Configuring HTTPS Servers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html): `It is possible to configure a single server that handles both HTTP and HTTPS requests`

Comment: @xofer: Interesting, but it seems that the keyword "ssl" was missing for port 443 directives. So maybe the port was working fine but with HTTP and not (as expected by browsers) with HTTPS.

Comment: will reply here because both of you will be notified. I've tried both and other server block setups. But I really doubt it's an nginx config issue.

Comment: @Jens Bradler: Yes, probably should drop `ssl on` too. I'd think it would run SSL on both ports, but who knows? @Simpleton: If none of this works, try commenting the IPv6 line.

Comment: No luck removing that line. NB have added edit.

Comment: Actually it must be something else as I have successfully tested above example. Could you please check your log files. Maybe the responsible issue will be mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't Nginx nor was it something anyone could have helped with so I'll leave this here in case anyone has this problem in future.

The problem was that port 443 was closed on Cloudflare as I was on the free plan. They do not support SSL on the free plan.